# References to subfigures which appear more than once in the document not in right order

Tags: cross-referencing, subfig

I have two figures A and B consisting of subfigures. Some subfigures appear in both of these figures. When I try to refer to the subfigures, the references appear in wrong order. For example:

```
\begin{document}

Figures \ref{fig:sub1}-\ref{fig:sub3} ...

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub1.png}
    \caption{Sub 1.}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub2.png}
    \caption{Sub 2.}
    \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub3.png}
    \caption{Sub 3.}
    \label{fig:sub3}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub4.png}
    \caption{Sub 4.}
    \label{fig:sub4}
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub1.png}  % <- appears second time
    \caption{Sub 1.}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub5.png}
    \caption{Sub 5.}
    \label{fig:sub5}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces "Figures 2b-1c ..."

How can I get the reference of sub1 to stay as Figure 1a, and not 2b?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX has no direct way of "knowing" that the graph shown in the `subfigure` that's numbered "1a" gets repeated in the `subfigure` that's numbered "2b".

For sure, it's not a good idea to employ non-unique `\label` directives. LaTeX issues the warning message

```
LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels
```

when it encounters, well, multiply-defined labels.

To make it clear to your readers that you wish to cross-reference one and the same graph across two separate `subfigure` environments (labelled `fig:sub1` and `fig:sub1_rep`, say), you may want to write

```
Figures \ref{fig:sub1} (also \ref{fig:sub1_rep}) and \ref{fig:sub3}, \dots
```

in the body of the document. And, to make it extra clear to your readers that the graphs are repeated deliberately, you could write something like `\caption{Sub 1, repeated.}` the second time the graph occurs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Figures \ref{fig:sub1} (also \ref{fig:sub1_rep}) and \ref{fig:sub3}, \dots

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub1.png}
    \caption{Sub 1.}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub2.png}
    \caption{Sub 2.}
    \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub3.png}
    \caption{Sub 3.}
    \label{fig:sub3}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{A group of three subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub4.png}
    \caption{Sub 4.}
    \label{fig:sub4}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub1.png} % <- appears second time
    \caption{Sub 1, repeated.}
    \label{fig:sub1_rep}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub1.png}
    \caption{Sub 5.}
    \label{fig:sub5}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Another group of three subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! I don't know how I didn't realize it myself :) But the writing tips are also very useful.